# Replacing Halogen with LED bulbs

Tags: electrical, led, halogen

I've just purchased some 12V LED MR-16 bulbs, intending to use them to replace the existing 12V Halogen MR-16 bulbs in my bathroom. I have found, much to my chagrin, that the LED bulbs seem to have different supply requirements.

**What do I need to do in order to replace the halogen bulbs with the LED bulbs I've purchased?**

The circuit to which the bulbs connect is 12V. Mains voltage is 240V here. To the best of my knowledge the LED bulbs are driver-less. Do I need to install a driver between each socket and the bulb, or does it just need to be somewhere on the 12V circuit? I do not have access to the 240V-12V transformer, even if I felt comfortable manipulating it.

I have tried the following configurations for the 4 sockets in my bathroom:

- 4 Halogen
- 2 Halogen, 2 LED
- 4 LED
- 1 LED

In each case the halogens act as would be expected: on when I switch the power on, off when I switch the power off.

When I switch on the power: The LEDs flash on, then go off and stay off.

When I switch off the power: LEDS stay off.

Comment: Please don't cross post to several Stack Exchange sites simultaneously - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14219/replacing-halogen-bulbs-with-led-bulbs - if you get the wrong site, or the question hasn't got the necessary attention after a few days, it can be migrated for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key difference:

- Halogen lights generally run from AC so this is what your transformer outputs.
- LED's require DC so generally yes, you will need a rectified output from your transformer.

I am guessing the transformer is providing enough forward voltage on initial switch-on, but not thereafter.

You may be able to add a rectifier circuit at each bulb location to cope with this.

Comment: Yup- Agreed on that- Halogen runs on Alternating Current (AC) - You will need to change the transformers to DC12Volt. To be hones I would stick with the halogens- better light. but the LED's don't give off heat I suppose and last longer.