# What do I need to do to change from Halogen to LED?

Tags: lighting, led

I want to update a few rooms in my house from halogen to LED light. The fittings I already have are for the MR 16 style (2 pins). Having the ability to dim the lights is not important.

I found information [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6270/replacing-halogen-with-led-bulbs) and online but I see suggestions of different circuits (rectifier circuit) or LED controllers.

Now I'm a complete novice, and a Google of either term brings up wiring drawings or ways to perform a light show.

My results did finally lead me to a choice of 2 things so my first question, what would I need, either [LED Constant Voltage Drive or an LED Constant Current Driver](http://www.screwfix.com/search.do?fh_search=led%20transformer&fh_view_size=20)

And my second question is, do I need one of these per LED bulb?

Comment: what kind of bulbs? like MR16/GU10, or standard base?  Do you require dimmers?

Comment: @Steven, Great question (+1) and I'm sorry for not making it clear. I've updated the question.

Comment: You can buy [dimmable MR16 LED lights](http://www.google.com/search?q=dimmable+led+MR16)

Answer (score 1):

The type of driver you need depends on the type of LED bulb you use. Apparently in your country, you can get Constant Voltage LED or Constant Current LED. Choose the matching driver.

Both types of drivers can drive more than one LED. Consult the data sheet for the exact limit.

However, if you have MR16 "fittings" with GU5.3 socket already, it is likely you don't need to replace the existing driver if you purchase Constant Voltage LED rated at 12V. If you have GU10 or screw (edison), that is more likely to be high voltage. That's how it is in the US, I don't know about your country.